# How to use search parameters with angularjs without hash?

Tags: angularjs

How do I use `$location` service with search parameters without the hash sign?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is referred to as HTML5 mode in the AngularJS docs. To turn it on:

```
angular
  .module('myApp',[])
  .config(function($locationProvider) {
      $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  });
```